# How to make inline text heading in Microsoft Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-word-2010, styles

I want to save Word document as PDF with Bookmarks.

I have a text:

```
Whoever created the mosquito’s eye, created the sun. 
Whoever ordered the flea’s stomach, ordered the solar system.
```

and want the word `mosquito’s eye` be `Heading 1` and the word `solar system` be `Heading 2` and these headings be shown on the navigation panel. Although I can assign such headings, however, it doesn't show up on the navigation panel, also created PDF doesn't have these headings as my bookmarks.

Need your help.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using "Style Separators", merging paragraphs with different paragraph styles. My source for this was [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/933368/191663) to "https://superuser.com/questions/607487/how-to-use-multiple-styles-within-a-single-paragraph-in-ms-word".

### `\paragraph{}` style headings.

The closest thing in common usage are LaTeX's `\paragraph{}` headings, which are headings that are typeset in bold, inline with the first subsequent paragraph. In order to emulate this behavior:

1. Write the heading text, formatted with the applicable heading style.
2. Write the body text as a separate paragraph. Now the text will look like

   > **Lorem ipsum.**
   >
   > Dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
3. Return to the heading line and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will merge the current paragraph with the next, but keep separate paragraph styles, including numbering and entry in the table of contents. It will now look like.

   > **Lorem ipsum.** Dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.

### Headings in the middle of the line, as asked

Having headings in the middle of the line is possible simply by merging the heading paragraph also with a text body paragraph *preceeding* it.

[image]

### Caveats

While this works, it can have awkward results. For instance, when text-body and heading style don't agree in paragraph alignment (typically "left" vs "justified"), it looks like the setting of the first style in the merged paragraph wins. Similar things apply for paragraph borders and spacing.

Inline headings also allow "section folding", as currently supported by Microsoft Word, but instead of only the section heading, the whole merged paragraph will remain visible.

Answer (score 0):

Inline text cannot be treated as a heading style as you probably know because it's a paragraph style.

Instead from memory heading styles are simply converted to "bookmarks" upon conversion to PDF so try wrapping that text as a bookmark instead.